# Can I switch to third-person while not in 'town' in Destiny 2?

Tags: destiny-2

I started playing recently, and in non-lethal areas, the player view automatically switches to third-person.

In story mode areas, it never does that. Haven't tried anything else like Crucible or Raids etc.

I checked the key mapping and could not find anything relevant to player view change.

Is there a way to switch to third person and back on demand?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No *Destiny 2* is a First Person Shooter and is marketed as such, for example, [on Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1085660/Destiny_2/). The only ways to go into third person are:

- In a safe social area: like the towns.
- If the weapon switches you to third person mode: like a sword.
- If you're driving a Sparrow.
- When using supers.
- During an emote.

There might be a couple of others but those are the ones I can remember off of the top of my head.

Comment: The sword point should be taken special note of.  You can pull out a sword anywhere and walk around which can be very useful in platforming sections, so it's advisable to always keep one in your inventory if you find this useful.

Comment: Well I mainly use swords in platforming sections if I want to 'airdash' with it but the camera probably helps too.